# Is it possible to install Kubernetes manually in my existing GCP VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am a newbie in Kubernetes. I have hosted my microservice application on the GCP VM instance. I want to use Kubernetes for deploying, managing, and scaling my applications. GCP provides GKE for that, but if I don't want to use that and installing Kubernetes manually in my existing VM instance.

Is it possible and how to install Kubernetes manually in my existing GCP VM instance?

Comment: You follow the directions for installing Kubernetes. It is extremely complex, which is why Google has a simple Kubernetes product.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thanks for the reply, Yeah it is extremely complex, but if somehow I installed it then google charges for computing resources? My main concern here is how to reduce my cost that's why I think if I install manually then it became beneficial for me or simply use google provided Kubernetes product.

Comment: @BhargavPatel `GKE` nodes are in fact `GCE` nodes and they are under the same pricing scheme. You can see it in the [GCP Pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator). Please review this [Kubernetes Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing) (additional fees). As for installing Kubernetes cluster on a `GCE` VM you can look on: [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/), [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/), [kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray).

Comment: It is god damn simple with Rancher. Prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @Michael Hampton this topic could be extremly complex and there is no one straight and correct solution.

This answer is to give/set more a baseline and reference than the actual solution.

---

Dividing this question on parts:

> Is it possible Kubernetes manually in my existing GCP VM instance?

In short, it's possible. There are a lot of options to choose from. Each solution will have it's advantages and disadvantages. It will also depend on the operating system your VM is deployed with.

**Some** of the options are the following:

- [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)
- [Kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/)
- [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/)
- [Kubespray](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray)
- [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/)
- [Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/quick-start-guide/deployment/google-gcp-qs/) <- as pointed by user @uav
- [Kelsey Hightower: Kubernetes the hard way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way)

> How to install Kubernetes manually in my existing GCP VM instance?

Each of the solutions linked above have a link to it's respective homepage. You can find there installation steps/tips. Each solution is different and I encourage you to check if selected option suits your needs.

> **A side note!**
>
> If you were to create a Kubernetes cluster on GCP with for example `kubeadm` please check if you have `IPIP`protocol allowed in your network.

---

This question will inherently go into the differences between provider-managed and self-managed Kubernetes solutions.

The general idea behind it is that in a provider-managed solution (like `GKE`, `AKS`, `EKS`) some aspects of provisioning, management, updates, logging and monitoring, etc. are taken care of by your cloud provider. With a cluster provisioned on a `GCE` VM (not using `GKE`) you will have a self-managed solution.

You will need to take care of updates, provisioning and also you will need to tailor (which could be a good thing) your installation to your specific needs (and requirements).

There are articles talking about differences between provider-managed and self-managed solutions. They can give a general idea about the aspects that I mentioned:

- *[Medium.com: SWLH: On premise Kubernetes clusters](https://medium.com/swlh/on-premise-kubernetes-clusters-b36660ca6914)*
- *[Magalix.com: Blog: Provider-managed vs self-managed Kubernetes](https://www.magalix.com/blog/provider-managed-vs.-self-managed-kubernetes)*

---

To estimate the difference in costs of running:

- `GCE` `VM` with a Kubernetes installed on top of it
- `GKE` single zone cluster with a single node

You can use:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Products: Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)*

I also encourage you to check the documentation about `GKE` pricing:

- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing)*

> **A note!**
>
> Additional fees may apply to other resources used in a project like static ip addresses, persistent disks used as `PVC`'s etc.

---

Additional reference:

- *[Kubernetes.io](https://kubernetes.io/)*
- *[Cloud.google.com: Kubernetes Engine: Docs: Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/quickstart)*